# Omit element that has null in collection during update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a value from a model by passing `ObjectId` as request body value. Sometimes it's updating and sometimes not updating. I found this is because in some record the `ObjectId` is null. When there is no null in the collection its updating fine. So I decide to omit the records that have `null` value in record and query the rest. But I am facing a issue. I couldn't query the collection that I manually stored from the null omitted record.

**Code**

```
accept = async (req, res) => {
    let ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId
    try {
        await this._model.find({
            person1: {
                $ne: null
            }
        }, (err, obj) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(obj);
                obj.update({
                    person1: new ObjectId(req.body.cid),
                    person2: new ObjectId(req.body.uid)
                }, {
                    $set: {
                        status: "active"
                    },
                }, (err, doc) => {

                    if (err) {
                        this.getErrorMsg(res, 522, null);

                    } else {
                        this.getErrorMsg(res, 227, doc);
                    }
                })

            }

        })
    } catch (err) {

        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

**Collection**

```
[{
   "_id":"5d2715cea9ae086ac295c6d8",
   "status":"pending",
   "person1":ObjectId("5cfe4dd898fd225ef1c99ded"),
   "person2":ObjectId("5d02197e2859122fa28c189b")
}
{
   "_id":"5d2715cea9ae086ac295c6d9",
   "status":"pending",
   "person1":ObjectId("5cfe4dd898fd225ef1c99dee"),
   "person2":ObjectId("5d02197e2859122fa28c189c")
}
{
   "_id":"5d2715cea9ae086ac295c6d0",
   "status":"pending",
   "person1":null,
   "person2":ObjectId("5d02197e2859122fa28c189f")
}]
```

**Error**

> TypeError: obj.update is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `person1: {$ne: null}` to the filter of update query.

Example:

```
await this._model.update({
  person1: {$ne: null, $eq: new ObjectId(req.body.cid)},
  person2: new ObjectId(req.body.uid)
}, {
  $set: {
    status: "active"
  }
})
```